# Excel FORMULA to sum values in multiple rows at the column with a specific word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, lookup

maybe it is easy but I can't get it to work :(

I'm trying to make an Excel formula to do the following:

- Find a specific column with the preset value
- sum the values of rows/cells at this column that also contains a specific word.

For Example: the table below:
[image: Excel Table Excample]

I want to find the column that has the value "Jul" and then go through this column's rows and sum all the rows that are "Pizza"

I hope someone could help me!

Thank u very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`SUMPRODUCT()` would be best for this case. Try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:H7)*(A2:A7=C11)*(B1:H1=D10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a sharm!

I have a following question, let's say the rows contain longer strings and "Pizza" is part of it and I want to say that the row_string should contains the C11 string value (e.g.: "*"&C11&"*") and not excat match it won't work and returns 0, do u know maybe why?

Comment: Then we have to go for different approach with different formula.

Comment: Would it also be possible to share this with me? I would appreciate it